# How to uninstall postgresql on snow leopard?

Tags: database, postgresql, uninstall, mac-osx

I used macports to install:

```
sudo port install postgresql83
```

Now I want to remove it, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
sudo port uninstall postgresql83
```